# VMWare - Error 500 from Server when trying to upload on a VM

Tags: vmware, vmware-server, esx

Say I have 2 "physical" ESXs which are both headed by a vSphere Server. What I am trying to do is to run a script which would upload a file to a specified VM. So basically, I use the VIFS.pl script provided by the VMWare community, the documentation of which is available here : http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcli.ref.doc%2Fvifs.html and the code source is here : http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10774 .

The source code is pretty simple, it simply uses the `http_put_file()` function from the `VIExt` module, and this function actually fails for me, since I get an Error 500, the log of which is here (I got it by printing `$resp->as_string()`) :

**do_put() function**

```
sub do_put {
   my ($local_source, $remote_target, $datacenter) = @_;
   my ($mode, $dc, $ds, $filepath) = VIExt::parse_remote_path($remote_target);
   # bug 322577
   if (defined $local_source  and -d $local_source) {
      VIExt::fail("Error: File to be uploaded cannot be a folder.");
   }

   # bug 266936
   unless (-e $local_source) {
      VIExt::fail("Error: File $local_source does not exist.");
   }

   my $resp = VIExt::http_put_file($mode, $local_source, $filepath, $ds, $datacenter);
   # bug 301206
   print $resp->as_string();   # => Trace
   if ($resp && $resp->is_success) {
      print "Uploaded file $local_source to $filepath successfully.\n";
   } else {
      print "Failed to upload !";
   }
}
```

** Trace **

```
# vSphere server : @192.168.20.2
# Datastore : nfs
# Datacenter : dc
# Target VM name : target_vm
# Target filename : VM.txt

>> perl vifs --server 192.168.20.2 --username root  --password root -p "/tmp/foo.txt" "[nfs] target_vm/VM.txt" -Z "dc"

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 6 Dec 2012 10:32:30 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text; charset=plain
Client-Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 11:32:53 GMT
Client-Peer: 192.168.20.2:443
Client-Response-Num: 9
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/ST=California/L=Palo Alto/O=VMware, Inc./CN=localhost.localdom CA 26fc6343/emailAddress=ssl-certificates@vmware.com
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Palo Alto/O=VMware, Inc./OU=VMware vCenter Server Certificate/emailAddress=ssl-certificates@vmware.com/CN=localhost.localdom/unstructuredName=1352217590,031bd875,564d7761726520496e632e
Client-SSL-Cipher: AES256-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified

Failed to upload !
```

Please not that I checked the value of all the variables passed as argument in the `http_put_file` function, they are all correct.

If someone ever experienced this problem, would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know some VMware, but have admittedly never tried to do what you're doing here, but I do have a thought to share with you.

If I'm not mistaken, your physical ESX host (192.168.20.2) is trying to place a file onto your VM (target_vm).  Since that communication is happening over port 443

```
    Client-Peer: 192.168.20.2:443
```

I'm guessing that the VMware certificates that are perhaps on your VM do not match the domain that those VM's have been added to (or they are not added to a domain).  The certificates look to be from 'localhost.localdom':

```
    CN=localhost.localdom
```

If you don't have a certificate authority in your domain already, perhaps you can quickly create a self-signed certificate for your domain and place it in the appropriate certificate store.  You also might want to try some of those other API calls like:

```
    --listds | -S
```

Maybe they won't require SSL to connect since it's not going over HTTPS?  That might validate that the certificates are, indeed, causing your problem?